# How to calculate the `font-size` from base size to viewports?

Tags: html, css, fonts

In my app, I am trying to set the `font-size` from the `mock-up`. but i am not getting correct result.

my mock-up width size is : `1280px` so, I resets the css for `10px` using the browser default `font-size`(16).  now my `1280px` view port has `62.5%` and i got `10px` exactly.

but how to calculate the font-size from this base size to other view ports?

i tried for view port size of `1600px` like this:

`1600/1280 = 1.25.. so 65.5/100 = 6.5 + 1.25 = 63.5%` - but i am not getting correct result here in `1600px` view port.

What is the correct way to calculate from the base site?

I am using `em` measurement here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) such as the followings:

- 1vw = 1% of viewport width
- 1vh = 1% of viewport height
- 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
- 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

So, calculate the size in viewport and use like this:

```
font-size: 1.25vw;
```

Also see [can i use viewport units?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

---

If you don't want to use viewport units and just use `em` then calculate the size like this:

If base font-size is 10px then `1em == 10px`. So, `1px = 1/10 = .1em` and to use font-size 16px then `.1*16 = 1.6em`

Comment: I am not interested with view=port width. in case of bigger monitor the font size is very big. i can't control that.

Comment: I want to calculate for different view port by percentage

Comment: Then calculate accordingly: 10px = 100% so 16px = 160%

Answer (score 0):

I calculated this way it works for me!

```
actual view port size = 1280

required view port size = 1600

variation = 1600/1280 = 1.25;

Base percent(1280) = 62.5 / 100 = 0.625

variation calulate = 1.25 * 0.65 = 0.78125 * 10 = 7.8125;

view port 1600 required = 62.5 + 7.8125 = 70.3125% as a base font.
```